# changing checkbox background color width styled components

Tags: reactjs

I want to control the background color of checkbox but something is wrong.
first,
I have a data like

```
export const data = [
{id: 1, checked: true},
{id: 2, checked: false},
{id: 3, checked: false},
]
```

and a component got this data is like

```
import {data} from "./data"
(...)
{data.map(item => <label key={item.id}> <input type="checkbox" checked={item.checked}/> </label>}
```

when i was trying to change the background color of label,
i wrote code like this...

```
background: ${props => props.checked ? "#000" : "transparent"};
```

but this doesn't work well. the label has background color transparent only. how can i handle this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case you could just use add `style={{background: item.checked ? "#000" : 'transparent'}}` to your label.

props refers to the values passed into a react component, in this case we're just using a regular label.

FYI - since you're hard-coding your data, your checkboxes won't be changeable - if thats something you need, you'll probably want to look at saving your data as a state, then modifying that based on the checkboxes being checked/unchecked.

```
const data = [
  {id: 1, checked: false},
  {id: 2, checked: true},
  {id: 3, checked: false},
]
  
const element = (
  <div>
    {data.map( item => (
      <label 
        key={item.id} 
        style={{background: item.checked ? "#000" : 'transparent'}}
      >
        <input type="checkbox" checked={item.checked} />
      </label>
    ))}
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```